# Regex to split chapter title

Tags: java, regex, split

I need split chapter's title to title number and title name. Format of chapters title is:

```
some long text
    3.7.2 sealant durability 
     paragraph with text        // (.*)
    3.7.3 funkční schopnost
     paragraph with text...
    3.1.13 plastic sealant xx 21    
     paragraph with text
    3.1.14 plastic sealant 
    xx 21   
     paragraph with text
    3.7.12 sealant durability
     paragraph with text
    3.7.325 funkční schopnost
```

**Edit:**
Problem is that, ilustrated values are between long text, full of special chars.

I used to follow code, but it splited only last digit after last dot. When I fill a "+" character after last "\d", is thrown an error. What is the correct regular expression for this problem?

```
title.trim().split("(?<=(\\d\\.\\d{1,2}\\.[\\d]))")
```

Expected output:

```
splitedValue[0] : '3.7.2'
splitedValue[1] : 'sealant durability'
...
splitedValue[0] : '3.1.14'
splitedValue[1] : 'plastic sealant xx 21'
...
```

[image]

Comment: How should `xx 21` be split? Also it would be better to see the xpected outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *split* is less suitable for your case than using precompiled regexp with groups for number and title. Below is the snippet that parses your test cases:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\d\\.]+)\\s+(.*)", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);

    List<String> input = Arrays.asList(
            "3.7.2 sealant durability",
            "3.7.3 funkční schopnost",
            "3.1.14 plastic sealant xx 21",
            "3.1.14 plastic sealant\n" +
                    "xx 21",
            "3.7.12 sealant durability",
            "3.7.325 funkční schopnost");

    for (String s : input) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        System.out.println("Input:" + s);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println("Number: " + matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println("Title: '" + matcher.group(2)+"'");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason you can't do `indexOf(' ')` to find the first whitespace character, and then substring on either side? That might be easier to work with, both for you and when the code gets looked at in five years.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the regular expression:

```
 *(\d+(\.\d+)*) (\p{L}+( \p{L}+)*)
```

`\p{L}` denote the category of Unicode letters. In ahother hand, you need to use a constant of Pattern for avoid recompiled the expression every time, something like that:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile(" *(\\d+(\\.\\d+)*) (\\p{L}+( \\p{L}+)*)");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "    3.7.2 sealant durability \n     paragraph with text        // (.*)\n    3.7.3 funkční schopnost\n     paragraph with text...\n    3.1.13 plastic sealant xx 21    \n     paragraph with text";

    Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // Chapter
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3)); // Title
    }
}
```

Use `matcher.find()` instead of `split()`.

Output:

```
3.7.2
sealant durability
3.7.3
funkční schopnost
3.1.13
plastic sealant xx
```

Answer (score 0):

Finding the first occurrence of spaces is a good idea, as @EricStein points out. You can also try something slightly more flexible like this:

```
String name = "3.7.2 sealant durability";
System.out.println(name.split("\\s+", 2)[1]);
```

```
sealant durability
```

More generally, in order to match your expected output:

```
String[] splitedValue = name.split("\\s+", 2);
```